# Please suggest free and reliable alternative(s) to MagicDisc on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-Bit

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, iso-image

[Suggested alternatives to MagicDisc](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/magicdisc/)

My issue with MagicDisc (from our internal wiki):

> Note: When you install and/or run
>   MagicDisc on Windows Server 2008,
>   Windows may display a software
>   compatibility warning about it (this
>   definitely happens on Windows Server
>   2008 R2, not sure about “plain”
>   Windows Server 2008). It appears that
>   you can safely ignore this, so far the
>   utility seems to work correctly
>   despite the warnings.
>
> Note:  This program is used to mount
>   .iso (cd image) files.  You will need
>   to mount a cd later when installing 16
>   below.   Because of incompatibilities
>   this software is not automatically run
>   on startup, you need to start it
>   yourself from the program menu.  To
>   use it, run the software, then right
>   click on the icon in the system tray,
>   select virtual CD/DVD-ROM -> any empty
>   disk -> Mount…  Then select your .iso
>   file.  Once mounted you can access the
>   cd image through explorer.

Please suggest your favorite and tell me why. Thanks!

Comment: You may have your reasons for wanting software specifically to mount ISO files.  But it should be noted that a more lightweight solution is software that will simply extract the contents of an ISO file.  Then you don't have to worry about virtual device drivers and compatibility so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say either [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home).

It is very hard to choose between them - both offer brilliant compatibility with the latest versions of Windows.

Daemon Tools used to be the best by far - it was recommended on various Microsoft sites (MSDN, Technet etc.) then they decided to release a premium version and cripple the free one (limited features and adware etc.). If you are willing to pay - Daemon tools is probably still the best.

If however you do not want to pay, I would say Virtual Clone Drive is brilliant - lightweight and it simply works - the company behind it has a rather checkered history with various companies due to some of their other products - however, Virtual Clone drive works brilliantly.

(I am just hoping Microsoft will release an update to their lightweight VCD program - at 80KB and quite portable (one file, with an easy install/remove) it was by far the best ISO program - but not working on Windows Vista/2008+)

Comment: Thanks, but Virtual Clone Drive does not appear to be free; it looks like Daemon Tools has a free version that will work for longer than 21 days.

Comment: @Fantomas - click my link - Virtual clone drive is free